# Ordinals with uncountable cofinality

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

How to construct an ordinal with uncountable cofinality? All the very "large" ordinals I can think of, such as $\omega_\omega^{\omega_\omega}$, still seem to have countable cofinality. I need a better intuitive sense of what such a large ordinal can be.

Relevant links:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality#Cofinality_of_ordinals_and_other_well-ordered_sets
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number

Comment: It's difficult to really get a sense for uncountable cofinalities, because by definition there's no (integer-)indexed sequence 'leading up to' that ordinal, but why not simply $\omega_1$, the ordinal of all countable ordinals ordered by set inclusion?

Comment: Pretty much every ordinal that you can "construct" is countable and hence has countable cofinality.

Comment: @LevonHaykazyan: It's hard for me to conceive a sensible notion of constructibility in which $\omega_\omega^{\omega_\omega}$ is constructible, but $\omega_1$ isn't...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think ${\omega_1}$ has countable cofinality, despite being uncountable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality#Cofinality_of_ordinals_and_other_well-ordered_sets

Comment: @tom4everitt Assuming the Axiom of Choice, $\omega_1$ has cofinality precisely $\omega_1$; its cardinal $\aleph_1$ is a so-called _regular_ cardinal.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_cardinal for the basics of regular cardinals, and why $\omega_1$ can't have countable cofinality assuming AC.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes, you're right, just realized. thanks

Answer (score 6):

For every ordinal $\alpha$ consider $\alpha+\omega_1$ (ordinal addition). Note that if $\alpha$ is countable (or finite) then the sum is equal to $\omega_1$ which has uncountable cofinality by the virtue of being a regular cardinal. In fact this trick works with *any* regular uncountable cardinal.

You can always use uncountable cardinals (with uncountable cofinality) as indices, e.g. $\omega_{\omega_{\omega_1}}$

By the way, if you feel that you can construct $\omega_\omega$ which is pretty uncountable, you already have many ordinals with uncountable cofinalities below it.

---

One note on constructive-ness of ordinals with uncountable cofinality, it requires some choice to prove there exists an ordinal with an uncountable cofinality, since it is consistent with ZF that there are none.

Comment: Why do you restrict $\alpha$ to uncountable ordinals?

Comment: @tomasz: Nothing particular, really. Just with countable ordinals you get $\omega_1$ which seems a bit... trivial? I suppose I will edit that in the answer.

Comment: So $\omega_1$ has uncountable cofinality? Perfect, I think I assumed it didn't since $\omega_\omega$ doesn't (which is much larger), but I see it now, I think. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @tom4everitt: Cofinality is not monotone, every $\omega$-many ordinals it returns to $\omega$, and every $\omega_1$ is [necessarily] hits $\omega_1$ again, and so on.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yes, you're right. But $\omega_1$ is the smallest ordinal with uncountable cofinality, right?

Comment: @tom4everitt: Yes, trivially too. Every ordinal below $\omega_1$ is countable, and of course that every countable ordinal has a countable cofinality! (This *does* require some choice though, as I remark in my answer.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, cool, just wanted to make sure I had got it right. thanks again