# Question Related to $G_\delta$ and $F_\sigma$

Tags: general-topology, abstract-algebra

I have question related to these two statements.

1. If $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic subsets of the real line $R$ and $X$ is an $F_\sigma$-set in $\mathbb{R}$, then $Y$ is an $F_\sigma$-set, too.
2. If $X$ is a [Tikhonov space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space), every [Cech-complete](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Cech-complete_space) subspace of $X$ is $G_\delta$-set.

I know the second statement is wrong but I have not counter-example. Also I want to know the outline proof of the first one.

Comment: Sorry, I updated. for the second one do we have any counter-example in case its not true in general ?

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use that a subset of the real line is $F_\sigma$ if and only if it is $\sigma$-compact.
2. Take $\omega_1+1=[0,\omega_1]$ with the order topology. Then singleton $\{\omega_1\}$ is Cech-complete, but not $G_\delta$.
   (Here $\omega_1$ denotes the first uncountable ordinal, and we consider the space of all countable ordinals together with the first uncountable ordinal.)

Here are some details related to 1. Say,$A=\cup_{n<\omega} F_n$ where each $F_n$ is closed. Then each $F_n$ is the union of countably many compact sets, namely $F_n=\cup_{k\ge1}\Bigl([-k,k]\cap F_n\Bigr)$, where each $\Bigl([-k,k]\cap F_n\Bigr)$ is closed-and-bounded, hence compact. It follows that $A$ is the union of countably many compact sets. Hence, if $f:A\to B$ is a homeomorphism, it follows that $B$ is the union of countably many compact sets. Since each compact subset of the real line is closed, $B$ is the union of countably many closed sets, hence $B$ is $F_\sigma$.

Details related to 2. Singleton $\{\omega_1\}$ is compact, hence Cech-complete. Take any countable family $\{U_n:n<\omega\}$ of neighborhoods of $\{\omega_1\}$. We may assume that these are basic open neighborhoods, that is there are $\beta_n$ such that $U_n=(\beta_n,\omega_1]$ for each $n$. Let $\beta=\sup_{n<\omega} \beta_n$, then $\beta<\omega_1$ (since sup of any countable set of countable ordinals is countable, since the union of countably many countable sets is countable). But, $\cap\{U_n:n<\omega\}=\cap_{n<\omega}\,(\beta_n,\omega_1] =(\beta,\omega_1] \not= \{\omega_1\}$. (Here $\omega$ is the first *infinite* ordinal, it is countable, same as $\Bbb N=\{0,1,..\}$ the set of all non-negative integers.)

Comment: thanks,please if you could give more detail on the second one.

Comment: I added some details for 2, the proof uses that $\omega_1$ has uncountable [cofinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality) see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203089/ordinals-with-uncountable-cofinality and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416218/in-zf-does-there-exist-an-ordinal-of-provably-uncountable-cofinality For $\omega_1$ see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal

Comment: thanks,the two link was useful+your answer.