# Definition of subsequence of a net

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, nets

I'm self studying Topology from Michael Gemignani's Elementary Topology. The author asks the following question (Exercise 2 on [page 127](https://books.google.com/books?id=q8TttGzVGxUC&pg=PA127)):

> Suppose $X,D$ is a metric space and $\{ s_i \} , i \in I$, is a net in
>   $X$ and suppose that $s_i \to x$. Prove that a subsequence of $\{ s_i
>  \} , i \in I$, converges to $x$.

I'm not sure what the author means by the subsequence of a net. The author defines subnets. Is subsequence of a net is a subnet indexed by the directed set $\mathbb{N}$? If so, we're done since we know that every subnet will converge to the same point where the net does.

---

Here's Gemignani's definition of subnet:

Let $\{ s_i \} , i \in I$ be a net in $X$. Let $J$ be a directed set and $k: J \to I$ such that

- if $j \le j'$ then $k(j) \le k(j')$
- if $i, i' \in I$, then there is $j \in J$ such that $i \le k(j)$ and $i' \le k(j)$.

The composition $s \circ k$ is said to be subnet of the net $\{ s_i \} , i \in I$.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the author means, but recall that sequences are particular cases of nets. Thus, a subsequence of a net could mean 'a subnet of the net which is actually a sequence'.

Comment: What is Gemignani's definition of a subnet?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I've updated in the description of my question.

Answer (score 2):

> Is subsequence of a net is a subnet indexed by the directed set $\mathbb{N}$?

Yes. The same definition is given in the book.

> If so, we're done since we know that every subnet will converge to the same point where the net does.

That depends. If the author literally meant "any subsequence of $(s_i)$ converges to $x$" then this is trivially true, as you've noted. Note that if $(s_i)$ has no subsequences (which can happen) then this is vacuously true.

However this interpretation doesn't bring anything new to the table. It seems that the author meant "$(s_i)$ **has** a subsequence convergent to $x$". Which unfortunately is not true in general. Recall the definition of a subnet:

> **Definition:** For a net $f:I\to X$ a subnet of $f$ is a net $g:J\to X$ together with a monotone, cofinal function $h:J\to I$ such that $f\circ h=g$.

Cofinal here means that the image of $h$ is cofinal with $I$.

And thus the second interpretation of the statement is false. Simply because there are [ordinals of uncountable cofinality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203089/ordinals-with-uncountable-cofinality). I.e. there is an ordinal $\lambda$ such that no countable subset of $\lambda$ is cofinal with $\lambda$. And so a constant net $t:\lambda\to X$, $t(i)=x$ is obviously convergent, but it has no countable subnet. Note that a constant sequence $x_n=x$ is not a subnet of $t$ - the cofinality axiom is not satisfied.

I think what the author wanted to say is that in metric spaces nets can be replaced with sequences. Meaning if $s:I\to X$ is a convergent net then there is a sequence $t:\mathbb{N}\to X$ convergent to the same limit and such that $im(t)\subseteq im(s)$. But such sequence need not be a subnet. Being a subnet is a stronger condition. For metric spaces pretty much any property requiring a net, can be stated with sequences instead.

Comment: The question is unclear:"prove that a subsequence of $s_i$ converges to $x$ " is true as stated: it actually means "if we have a subsequence, then it converges to $x$" which is indeed obvious. But the author of the text certainly meant that such a subsequence *exists*, which is a novel element, and true of course.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Indeed, this is unclear. I've updated the answer. I don't think a subsequence needs to exist.

Comment: @freakish I think the statement holds (for any first-countable $T_1$ space) once you add the hypothesis that the net in question is not eventually constant. So while your counterexample is technically correct, it is essentially the *only* counterexample.