# Question on metric spaces and nets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, nets

I am self studying Topology from Gemignani's Elementary Topology. Here's the question which I am trying to prove (Exercise 2 on [page 127](https://books.google.com/books?id=q8TttGzVGxUC&pg=PA127)):

> Let $X,D$ be a metric space and $\{ s_i \}, i \in I$ be a net in $X$.
>   If every subsequence of $\{ s_i \}$ converges to $x$, then show that
>   $\{ s_i \}$ converges to $x$.

Suppose that $\{ s_i \}$ does not converge to $x$. Now, we're trying to find a subsequence which does not converge to $x$. By the definition, there is a open set $U$ containing $x$ such that for all $i \in I$, $s_j \not\in U$ for some $j \in I$ with $i\le j$. With this, I can easily construct $k : \mathbb{N} \to I$ such that $k$ is monotone and $s_{k_n} \not\in U$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The only problem I am facing is to find $k$ which satisfies all the properties. I notice that I couldn't even use the "niceness" that metric spaces offer in construction of such a function $k$.

Can someone drop some hints so that I complete this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you find the **definition** of subsequence in this text? It cannot mean subnet with domain $\Bbb N$ as we would logically expect, because then this (and your previous) question are false.

Comment: If the net does not converge we have that there exists on open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $$\forall i \in I: \exists j: (j \ge i) \land (s_j \notin U)$$ But this gives you no chance to use special properties of metric spaces.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Author never formally defines a subsequence of a net. He "italicizes" the first time he makes use of it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1821t1AD-V4mYAMiC5aYGQ4b0i8mHd4It/view?usp=drivesdk . See exercise 4 (page 122), I've attached Example 1 as well. The book is partially available on Google Books.

Comment: If it helps, kindly let me know what the author is trying to mean by a "subsequence" of a net.

Comment: exercise 4 on 122 on your scan mentions *subsequence*, so it must have been defined before that page. So scan the pages before too if you will.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma here's the scan: https://drive.google.com/file/d/199vKW7ltuvud3gbvs8Z_ujx03q-_3Brw/view?usp=drivesdk he does define subsequence but it isn't different from our definition, I believe

Comment: He does explicitly say (p120 third line, and before) that a subnet that is a sequence (so defined on $\Bbb N$) is customarily called a subsequence of the net. So all remarks by freakish and myself still stand for both this and the previous question.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes, I'll just skip those exercise problems which include the word "subsequence" and move ahead. There's nothing much that can be done. Can you suggest me a topology textbook at the undergraduate level which covers Nets and Filters? I haven't studied ordinals and cardinals yet and it seems to me that you made a reference to that in order to disprove the author's claim.

Comment: Well, consider the directed set of all functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ ordered by almost dominance: $f \le g$ iff $\{n \in \Bbb N: g(n) > f(n)\}$ is at most finite. This is also a directed set with no countable cofinal set, so no subsequences. Ordinals and cardinals are not strictly needed. Also, a free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$ doesn't have a countable cofinal subset under reverse inclusion-ordering etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an a way a continuous of your previous question and Freakish's answer to it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3686492/4280) is still relevant and shows that this statement is wrong: Let any $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in \omega_1}$ be any net into $X$ defined on $\omega_1$, standard order. Then in Gemignani's definition, these net has **no** subsequences (convergent or otherwise) so vacuously we can say that "all subsequences of $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in \omega_1}$ converge to $x$, whatever $x$ is. If your statement would hold we could conclude that $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in \omega_1}$ converged to $x$, which would almost certainly be false (for all most all $x$ and spaces $(X,d)$).

In short, I'm sceptical. Maybe subsequence has a special meaning on this text (check the index to find the definition?), as @freakish suggested (so not a special subnet).